# only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

The code that I am looking at is:

```
ids = np.delete(ids, np.concatenate([ids[-1]], np.where(ious > thresh)[0]))
```

The values for the different variables is:

ids: `[3 2 0 1]`

ious: `[0.         0.65972222 0.65972222]`

thresh: `0.5`

The output of `np.where(ious > [thresh])[0])` is `[1 2]`

The error I seem to be getting is:

```
    np.where(ious > [thresh])[0]))
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

I am certain that every variable except for `thresh` is a `numpy` array. So what exactly is going wrong.

Comment: The second argument to `concatenate` has to be a scalar, the axis.

Comment: @hpaulj The output to the where is a list of indices, I'll make a change to the question to indicate so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [187]: ids=np.array([3,2,0,1])                                                         
In [188]: ious=np.array([0.  ,       0.65972222, 0.65972222])                             
In [189]: thresh=0.5
```

Testing the `where`:

```
In [190]: np.where(ious>thresh)                                                           
Out[190]: (array([1, 2]),)
In [191]: np.where(ious>thresh)[0]                                                        
Out[191]: array([1, 2])
In [192]: np.where(ious>[thresh])[0]                                                      
Out[192]: array([1, 2])
```

now the `concatenate`:

```
In [193]: np.concatenate([ids[-1]], np.where(ious > thresh)[0])                           
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-193-c71c05bfaf15> in <module>
----> 1 np.concatenate([ids[-1]], np.where(ious > thresh)[0])

TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
In [194]: np.concatenate([ids[-1], np.where(ious > thresh)[0]])                           
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-194-91ed414d6d7c> in <module>
----> 1 np.concatenate([ids[-1], np.where(ious > thresh)[0]])

ValueError: zero-dimensional arrays cannot be concatenated
In [195]: np.concatenate([[ids[-1]], np.where(ious > thresh)[0]])                         
Out[195]: array([1, 1, 2])
```

now the `delete`:

```
In [196]: np.delete(ids,np.concatenate([[ids[-1]], np.where(ious > thresh)[0]]))          
Out[196]: array([3, 1])
```

Comment: This works, but can you explain as to why the `[[ids[-1]]` is needed. Why do we need a nested array here?

Comment: `ids[-1]` is an element of `ids`, Type is `np.int64` and shape is `()`, what the error calls 'zero-dimensional'.  `concatenate` (without axis) joins the arguments on their 1st axis.  A 0d array doesn't have a 1st axis.  All inputs to `concatenate` must has the same number of dimensions.  `np.array([ids[-1]])` has shape (1,).

Comment: but then a `[ids[-1]]` would lead to a 1d array right? I used a solution where I did a `ids = np.delete(ids, np.concatenate(([len(ids) - 1], np.where(ious > thresh)[0])))`